# GDSL for defining the delegate of Closures in annotations

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

Spock has some annotations that take a closure as argument, e.g., `@Requires({ os.windows })`. The annotations are defined as follows (omitting irrelevant information):

```java
public @interface Requires {
  Class<? extends Closure> value();
}
```

When evaluating the annotation Spock sets a `PreconditionContext` as delegate for the closure before evaluating it. So if it where a normal method we could define it as

```
boolean checkCondition(@DelegatesTo(PreconditionContext) Closure condition) {
 // ...
}
```

but we can't use the `@DelegatesTo` annotation for `METHOD`/`TYPE_USE` targets.

Unfortunately, IntelliJ's GDSL is sparsely documented, I found a [nice blog series](https://www.tothenew.com/blog/gdsl-awesomeness-introduction-to-gdsl-in-intellij-idea/) and the "official" [documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/GRVY/Scripting+IDE+for+DSL+awareness), but all I could find therein are examples for closures as method arguments.

So, is it possible do define the delegate of an annotation closure with a gdsl script and how do you do it?

Comment: Here's the Groovy ticket for this, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-9510

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out:

The `closureScope` has an `annotationName` parameter, with it you can define that you want closures in that named annotation. I had to sift through IntelliJ's code base to discover this.

With this knowledge it is easy to create the necessary point-cut for all annotations using this snippet.

```
def conditionalExtensions = ['spock.lang.Requires', 'spock.lang.IgnoreIf', 'spock.lang.PendingFeatureIf'].collect { annot -> context(ctype: "spock.lang.Specification", scope: closureScope(annotationName: annot))}
contributor(conditionalExtensions, {
    delegatesTo(findClass('org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.PreconditionContext'))
})
```